# captcha not work on login form in joomla website

Tags: joomla, captcha, joomla3.0, recaptcha, joomla-extensions

I enabled the reCaptcha plugin on my Joomla website. But the captcha doesn't show on the login page (login form).
How can I use captcha (reCaptcha or other plugin) on login page in a Joomla website?

Comment: have you enable captcha for user manager?

Comment: A password is way better than a captcha if you have good captcha on the registration page.

Answer (score 1):

The CAPTCHA field is not included with the login form so it won't appear whether you enable the plugin or not.

If you really need a CAPTCHA on the login form then your best option is to implement a plugin which adds the CAPTCHA field to the form when the page is loaded.